# ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON static broadcastreceiver in android 3.0+

Tags: android, class, android-activity, static, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to capture the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent using a broadcastreceiver in Android 3.0+.

My receiver is a static inner class of my MainActivity class. It is static, because it is registered in my AndroidManifest.xml and it has to find the class. However, this means that my BroadcastReceiver has no way of getting back to my activity when the play/pause button is pressed. The onReceive method gets called, but because the class is static, I can't inform my activity.

Using a reference to my activity or a Handler object also does not work, since I can't acquire the BroadcastReceiver object that is being called by the Android system.

Dynamically declaring the receiver should also work, but this does not work on Android 3.0+, for some strange reason. It has something to to with:

```
AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(ComponentName)
```

Which is required to be called.

Some illustration of my class:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public static class MicReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            // onReceive is called
                // How do I inform MainActivity of the press?
        }
    }
```

Do you have any ideas for a fix?

Thanks!

[EDIT]
See my code below for registering my receiver dynamically: (This is currently not working)

```
mReceiver = new RemoteControlReceiver();

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
filter.setPriority(2147483647);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), RemoteControlReceiver.class.getName()));
```

Comment: Why are you not using `registerReceiver()`, instead of putting the receiver in the manifest? What are you trying to do with media button presses when your activity is not in the foreground?

Comment: I would like to do nothing when my activity is not in the foreground, but else it does not work. I'm using this code in my onCreate to try to dynamically register it. (See edit)

Comment: Ah, I see, `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()` is what is expecting something in the manifest. Are you sure that you need to bother with `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()`, given that you are the foreground activity? Can't you find out about these presses using the standard `onKeyEvent()` instead?

Comment: Yes this does the trick. Thank you. I can create the final answer to accept it, but maybe it's better for you to it, since you'll get REP ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()` is if you want to receive media button events in the background. A foreground activity can find out about media button events using [the standard `onKeyDown()` callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring receiver in Manifest will try to instantiate the receiver and call `onRecieve()`, even when activity is not around.

To make it an activity bound receiver, make it a non static class and instantiate it in `onCreate()`. Then, register and unregister it in `onResume()`  and `onPause()` respectively. Since class is non static and registered only when activity is active, you can safely call parent activity methods from inner receiver class.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this if you want to process something in BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public static class MicReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MicReceiver() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

          Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }



        }
    }
```